# Select2 infinite scroll with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

[Here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#infinite) could be find an example "with Remote Data". Is it possible to replace it with local storage (js array) or better to combine local with Remote Data? I want to populate first page with items from array and use ajax for following pages if user wants more.

```
{
        multiple: true,

        ajax: {
            url: "/myproducts/categories",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    pageNumber: page
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page) {
                var more = (page * 10) < data.Total;
                return { results: data, more: more };
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got this problem too. Currently, select2 does not support this feature. You can see [the issue](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/684).

Comment: I just found an workaround https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/371

Comment: have you tried using the `initSelection` function